# (RESTFUL api Javascript get function) How to return 0 if account is not found in mapping?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, mapping

I have a mapping

```
"balances": {
  "1": "1000",
  "2": "2000",
  "3": "3000",
}
```

How do return 0 if the account number cant be found?

my code so far is

```
app.get('/GetBalanceByAddress/:id', function (req, res) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(balances.balances[req.params.id], null, 4));
});
```

for example, right now
/GetBalance/1 returns 1000

/GetBalance/2 returns 2000

/GetBalance/3 returns 3000

and /GetBalance/4 returns nothing.

How do i get /GetBalance/(AnyNonExistentAddress) to return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, please use try catch or if statement.

```
app.get('/GetBalanceByAddress/:id', function (req, res) {
  try{
    res.end(JSON.stringify(balances.balances[req.params.id]));
  }
  catch{
    res.end("0");
  } 
});
```

or

```
app.get('/GetBalanceByAddress/:id', function (req, res) {
  if (balances.balances[req.params.id]) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(balances.balances[req.params.id]));
 
  }
  else {
    res.end("0");
  }  
});
```

Comment: tried it returns nothing when i try getbalance/4 for both

Comment: res.end means end the response, so please try res.send instead of  res.end..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ES2020 compatible browser, you can use the [`nullish coalescing operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```js
const balances = { "balances": {
  "1": "1000",
  "2": "2000",
  "3": "3000",
}
};

let id = 1;
console.log(balances.balances[id] ?? 0);
id = 4;
console.log(balances.balances[id] ?? 0);
```

Comment: im using req.params though

Comment: @TIMMY123 I just used `id` to demonstrate how the code works (I didn't want to set up a multi-level object just for a small demo). You would use `req.params.id` where I have `id`.

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap in a try/catch block

```
app.get('/GetBalanceByAddress/:id', function (req, res) {
  try{
    res.end(JSON.stringify(balances.balances[req.params.id], null, 4));
  });
  }
  catch{
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: tried it returns nothing when i try getbalance/4

Comment: try res.send(0) instead of return 0